# Google Earth Engine: Computation timed out error while extracting time-series of values to points

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2, google-earth-engine-python-api

I am using the python API of the google earth engine and [geemap](https://geemap.org/) library to work with sentinel-2 imagery for the contiguous United States. Here is the code I am using:

```
def maskS2clouds(image):
    """Function to mask clouds using the Sentinel-2 QA band
    Args: {ee.Image} Sentinel-2 image
    Retrns:  {ee.Image} cloud masked Sentinel-2 image"""
    
    qa = image.select('QA60')

    # Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
    cloudBitMask = 1 << 10
    cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11
    # Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
    mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0) \
      .And(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0))
    return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000)

startdate = ee.Date('2019-01-01')
enddate = ee.Date('2019-01-15')
s2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR') \
    .filterDate(startdate, enddate) \
    .filterBounds(conUS) \
    .filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 10) \
    .map(maskS2clouds) \
    .select(['B2','B3', 'B4', 'B8', 'B11', 'B12']) \
    .sort('system:time_start')
```

After this, I use the following to obtain the time-series.

```
timeseries_s2 = s2 \
            .toBands() \
            .clip(conUS)
```

My goal is to extract the time-series values for the selected sentinel-2 bands at ~16,000 geographical points all over the United States.

```
extract_s2 = geemap.extract_values_to_points(path_aqspy, timeseries_s2, crs='EPSG:4326', scale=10)
geemap.ee_to_csv(extract_s2, 's2.csv')
```

However, I keep getting the **Computation timed out** error. Right now, I am only trying to use two weeks of imagery but want to filter over months eventually.
The above code works fine if I extract the time-series values for a few hundred points.